# Key press autocomplete queries to a 3 million rows table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, autocomplete, innodb

I have a table `fs_city`, with 3 millions cities all around the world, as well as a table `fs_country`.

When the user visits the website it detects its country code, the user is required to select their country and city from a box (which looks for cities in `fs_city` on key press), if the user is from USA, and types "Ne", he will get a drop down list with "New York" for i.e. I do this to create an autocomplete input.

The problem is that, the query is sent upon every key press, in my example "Ne", there are two queries to the table `fs_city`.

Also, even if there's only one query, it takes 6 seconds to return a response from that table... My table has primary keys.

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    ci.city_id,
    ci.country_code,
    ci.city,
    ci.region,
    co.country_name
FROM 
    fs_city as ci,
    fs_country as co
WHERE
    ci.city LIKE "Ne%"
    AND co.country = ci.country_code
    AND ci.country_code = :country
ORDER BY 
    ci.city ASC 
    LIMIT 0,20
```

How can I create an autocomplete feature (with keypress), and how to speed up `fs_city` table queries?

**Updated :**

fs_city primary key : city_id

fs_country primary key : country_id

Engine : InnoDB

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at caching your search results with something like [Redis](http://redis.io/)

Comment: Caching no doubt - but no  DB schema is exposed, no information on indexes, so for all we know, its scanning the table - you need to provide the schema info.

Comment: Don't trigger the autocomplete until at least three characters have been entered

Comment: You could reduce the load by NOT checking until after the user stops typing for a couple seconds, not checking until the second or third char is entered, and then locking out the ajax request until the previous lookup completes. there is no point in firing off an lookup for every keypress as soon as the key's pressed... if the user makes a typo, now you've wasted an ajax request/lookup sequence.

Comment: And make sure you have an index on country_code and city in your fs_city table

Comment: @Redis, Andrew .. Nice point, I'm going to use memcache ... I just desabled it in development mode for testing purposes.

I will update my question with the schema included.

Comment: @MarkBaker Marc B , Yeah, I'm gonna do that ... but as you see, even in a case of one request, the table takes 6 - 7 seconds return results

Comment: Then give use details of the table structure and __indexes__, and do you really need to return the country name via the join when it's pre-selected anyway.... that would reduce the overhead of a join

Comment: @MarkBaker .. Yes, I need to return the country name to display it after the city in the autocomplete box. fs_country is the table containing the country name.

I added infos about the table, it's InnoDB and the primary key is city_id

Comment: In addition to only sending the request after three characters also cache the result and additionally only resend if the keystroke has contradicted a previously received response not just a previously sent request. i.e. if you receive Constantinople in response to con dont resend when they have typed consta. You need to look at your 6 seconds. The SQL end should be sub-second even for 3 million cities and utf8.

Comment: @ClearCrescendo , Nice catch ... I'm going to activate memcache, as well as the considering to apply the solution you just mentioned.

I'm now working on table's performance, I think I'll go for MyISAM Engine.

Comment: Yeah guys, As I expected... InnoDB is not good for large read tables. I switched to MyISAM and it's now returning results in 1.72 seconds per query. This is also slow, but it's better than 7 sec per query.

Next step, I'll go with the solution suggested by @cujomalainey in the answer.

Comment: You should already have the country from the users selection, so I'm not quite sure why you need it returned by the query as well... you can inject it into the front-end drop-down in js if you really need to display it again

Comment: Have you added a composite key to the fs_city table on both country_code and city?

Comment: @MarkBaker You're right about the country, I just removed it from my query.

For the composite key, no.. I didn't use it. All I used is the primary key on city_id

Comment: Then you also want a key on city..... that's the column you're actually searching on

Comment: okey, I'm gonna do this too @MarkBaker, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has nice widget with exactly what you are looking for and I'm pretty sure you can limit it to only start query the database after a set amount of characters so you can limit your results. That should solve your speed problem and shorten your javascript. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

**EDIT** MySQL also has a LIMIT term to cap the return, which might also help.

Comment: What if you are trying to enable through a restful api in a mobile app?  I am using PHP and Angular.js to be specific.

Comment: @Joti Basi most restful APIs can take a count and page parameters, you can use those to scope your results by translating them into parameters for LIMIT.